# Excluir objetos de Listas

Tags: python, lista, random

Tenho uma lista gerada por números aleatórios (`random.sample`), porém quero excluir esses objetos selecionados da lista.
Já tentei `remove` e `del`, mas não dá certo:

```
from random import sample
l1= []
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
x = sample(l2,2)
l1.insert(0,x)
l2.remove(l1)
print(l2)
```

Erro:

> ```
> *ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list*
> ```

Comment: esse erro ocorre porque você estava tentando apagar um elemento de l2 usando o elemento l1, que é atualmente uma lista vazia.

Comment: Não precisa do `x`, pode fazer direto `l1 = sample(l2, 2)`. E depois precisa fazer um loop pra remover os elementos da outra lista: `for i in l1: l2.remove(i)`

Comment: Só lembrando que **se** as listas forem muito grantes, esse `for` pode não ser o jeito mais eficiente. Veja [este teste](https://ideone.com/yxD33z), por exemplo, o `for` é cerca de 5 vezes mais lento. Claro que para listas pequenas e/ou rodando poucas vezes não fará diferença, mas enfim

Answer (score -1):

Estás a inserir uma lista dentro de uma lista e a fazer remove de uma lista. Tens de usar um ciclo para inserir e remover um item de cada vez.

```
from random import sample

l1 = []
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
x = sample(l2,2)

for i in x:
    l1.insert(0,i)

for i in l1:
    l2.remove(i)

print(l2)
```